# Multiple tbodys and scroll inside the 1st & column width issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im'm trying to get a scrollable first Tbody inside this table with fixed header, divided in 4 tbodies witch look like this : http://scr.hu/0ei9/k2tqx
Here's the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yb5sob07/  (sorry for the html but it's a lot of code generated by angular and difficult to clean up for the fiddle...)

in short it looks like this :

```html
<table class="planning shifts">

  <thead>
    <!-- les jours du mois-->
    <tr class="bg-active">
      <th>Coursier|Jour</th>
      <th class="monthDay">Days from 1 to 31
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="shiftsTable">

    <tr>
      <td class="coursierTD">
        <a href="#">{{user.name}}</a> 

      </td>

      <td>user/day
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>




  <tbody ng-repeat="city in cities">
    <tr class="cityManquesHeader">
      <th colspan="{{calendar.monthDays.length+1}}">
        LAUSANNE
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Manques
      </td>
      <td>days</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <tr class="cityManquesHeader" ng-click="slideManques($event)">
        <th colspan="{{calendar.monthDays.length+1}}">Doublons</th>
      </tr>


      <tr>
        <td>Doublons</td>
        <td>days</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

For now the css can be summarized to this:

```css
.planning.shifts{ //<table> selector
  table-layout: fixed;
  tbody:first-of-type {
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 10000%;
    height: 300px;

  }
  thead:first-of-type  {
    tr {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
    }
  }
  th, td {

    text-align: center;
  }
  td:nth-child(1), th:nth-child(1) { width: 110px; }
  td:nth-child(2), th:nth-child(2){ width: 50px; }
  td:nth-child(3), th:nth-child(3) { width: 40px; }

}
```

As you can see there are several problems. The tbody does scroll but nothing really matches the cells' and column's widths.

With display:block I also loose the colored columns. And I don't understand why I had to set width to 10000% so I can see anything in the first tbody, in other case it would stay really tiny, not even the width of the first column.

Also, it has consequences on the tbodies beneath, the first columns seems to be passed through.
The nth-child seems to work only for the first occurence of each child (for the 1st one, for the 2nd one and the 3rn, not further).

I tried with some plugins like dataTables and it would be ok, if not the fact, that (if you look at day 25) some columns may be larger than others and this width isn't taken into account by the other lower tbodies, and it should (something that already works if there is no display:block).

Well, a lot of problems...any ideas how to work this out?

Comment: It's difficult to say by just looking at a screenshot. Can you post to jsbin or fiddle?

Comment: yep, check this https://jsfiddle.net/yb5sob07/  and my edit.
it's kinda like this, sorry for the messy html.